# Multiplicative order of n mod 2n-1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the smallest positive integer k such that 
$n^k \equiv 1 \mod(2n-1)$.  Has this been solved?  Any thoughts or references are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about, say, $k=0$?

Comment: Oops, yes, I of course want $k$ to be positive.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the sequence that you are looking for: [A002326](http://oeis.org/A002326)

Comment: That's the order of  $\ 2\ mod (2n+1)$, I'm looking for the order of  $\ n\ mod (2n-1)$.

My Google search didn't find the sequence in OEIS, but maybe it's there..  Do you have a good way to find such things beyond basic Google searches? 

Thanks!

Comment: A002326 is the same as the sequence you are looking for up to the end of the OEIS entry at $n=73$.  I find this surprising but perhaps there is a simple reason?  Anyone?

Comment: @user160371 Re: my previous comment: the OEIS entry starts at $n=0$, so the same list, if we start counting at $n=1$, gives the order of $2$ modulo $2n-1$ rather than $2n+1$.  And this is the same as the order of $n$ because $2$ and $n$ are inverses modulo $2n-1$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem.  BTW instead of a keyword search, often the easiest way to find this kind of thing is to calculate a few terms, eg with Maple: seq(numtheory[order](n,2*n-1),n=2..20), and copy and paste the result into OEIS.